# Shell commands to match key value pairs

Tags: regex, shell, scripting

I've got a file that contains a list of `key=value` pairs, each on its own line. What's the best way to fetch the value for a specified key using shell commands?

Comment: bourne, C, or bash shell

Comment: I ended up with this:
grep "key" filename | sed '/key=//'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what about

```
grep "key" my_file | cut -d'=' -f2
```

Comment: What if the file has a horizontal list of key=value parameters?

Comment: Poster said "each on its own line". But yes, if there were more than one per line then this would not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it in ksh.

```
FOO=$(grep "^key=" $filename | awk -F"=" '{print $2}')
```

You can also use cut instead of awk. If you delimit the key pair with a space you can drop the -F"=".

Comment: grep can be omitted. awk can do it all. `awk -F"=" '/^key=/{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

```
read -r -p "Enter key to fetch: " key
awk -vk="$key" -F"=" '$1~k{ print "value for "k" is "$2} ' file
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
Enter key to fetch: key1
value for key1 is value1
```

or you can just use the shell(eg bash)

```
read -r -p "Enter key to fetch: " key    
while IFS="=" read -r k v
do
    case "$k" in
        *"$key"* ) echo "value of key: $k is $v";;
    esac
done <"file"
```

Comment: may not even need a regexp: `awk ... '$1 == k {print $2}' file`

Comment: depends. if OP needs exact match. If not, regexp is appropriate. OP can implement a SQL "like" equivalent with regexp.